# Hugging Face Pipeline behind Proxies - Windows Server OS

Tags: windows, machine-learning, deep-learning, proxy, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to use the Hugging face pipeline behind proxies.
Consider the following line of code

```
from transformers import pipeline
sentimentAnalysis_pipeline = pipeline("sentiment-analysis")
```

The above code gives the following error.

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english/resolve/main/config.json (Caused by ProxyError('Your proxy appears to only use HTTP and not HTTPS, try changing your proxy URL to be HTTP. See: [https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy'](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy%27), SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1091)'))))

I tried to check the proxy on my machine having OS - "windows server 2016 Datacenter" using the following code.

```
import urllib.request
print(urllib.request.getproxies())
```

The output is as follows:

```
{'http': 'http://12.10.10.12:8080', 'https': 'https://12.10.10.12:8080', 'ftp': 'ftp://12.10.10.12:8080'}
```

However, as per the documentation from [urlib3](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#https-proxy-error-http-proxy) page, the above setting is incompatible and the problem lies in the https setting :

```
{  
"http": "http://127.0.0.1:8888", 
"https": "https://127.0.0.1:8888"  # <--- This setting is the problem! 
}
```

and the right setting is

```
{  # Everything is good here! :)
  "http": "http://127.0.0.1:8888",
  "https": "http://127.0.0.1:8888"
}
```

How can we change the proxy setting from `"https": "https://127.0.0.1:8888"` to `"https": "http://127.0.0.1:8888"` in a windows OS?

I tried by setting the windows environment variable name as `"https_proxy"` and the variable values as `http://127.0.0.1:8888`. However, It is not working.

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution and it is pretty simple. Include the following lines in your python script/notebook. Change the proxy_url and port as per your setting. I hope it helps, someone in the community.

```
import os
os.environ['HTTP_PROXY'] = 'http://proxy_url:proxy_port'
os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] = 'http://proxy_url:proxy_port'
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Method 1 (recommended): `pypac`

```bash
pip install pypac
```

Monkeypatch the requests libary.

```py
import requests
import pypac

def request(method, url, **kwargs):
    with pypac.PACSession() as session:
        return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

requests.request = request
```

`transformers` should now work as expected.

```py
from transformers import pipeline
sentimentAnalysis_pipeline = pipeline("sentiment-analysis")
```

#### Method 2: Disable SSL verification

**WARNING**: This method could expose you to malicious attacks.

Disabling SSL verification is a bad idea in general, but the story *even worse* here because (afaik) `transformers` may download code and run `exec` on it. This opens the door for a man-in-the-middle to execute arbitrary code on your machine.

This is probably a very bad idea unless you *really* know what you're doing or you don't care at all about your machine's security.  Otherwise, do *not* use this method.

```py
import requests
import functools

requests.request = functools.partial(requests, verify=False)
```

### Explaination

Setting the `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables might not be enough to get through your corporate firewall. It may be using a `.pac` to autoconfigure its proxy on your machine. Browsers pick file up and use it automatically, as do some development tools (e.g. JetBrains). The `requests` library does not appear to do so.

Fortunately, there is a library called PyPAC that can does this for you. But you'll need to monkeypatch `requests` to use PyPAC's `request` method rather than its own.

You don't need to patch `requests.get` since that function delegates to `requests.request` anyway.

Comment: What if my proxy needs authentication and I don't want to store my password as plaintext either in a file or type it in a command? Can PyPAC handle this?